# Get both console and tty after upgrade Debian to Jessie 8.0 in openvz

Tags: console, debian, tty, openvz, proxmox

[image]

I can not use this machine via proxmox's console, because there are both console and tty, I confirmed that this problem came after dist-upgrade!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just fix this by removing:

/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service

and it now tty1 is gone. Still don't know if it will breaks anything.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks!
But before upgrade, it's tty1, I think it'll be better to be tty1 but not console?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe console is ok? Since on OpenVZ beta Debian 8 template, it is also console. (When logged in, it say tty1 though.)

Comment: yeah, anyway, I think I can accept your answer, nice work, thanks!